# Branch ID missing from web db

Tags: content-editor, branch

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 Update 3. I created an item with a branch template, and I see that template/ID in the "Created From" area of the quick info. However, when I publish to the web database, the "Created From" goes back to "unknown."

I've republished the branch template to web and confirmed it's there, so I don't know why the ID would be disconnected going to web. We're using code that's checking if there's a specific branch ID, so this is pretty important.

We just upgraded from 8.1 Initial, and I confirmed this is working properly there. I've opened a ticket with Sitecore but wanted to see if anyone here has run into something similar.

Comment: 2 cents here; but I can't think of any valid reason to use "Created From" at runtime.

Comment: The client's code is doing a check for item.BranchId. It was a migration project, so we weren't rewriting or refiguring things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore Support said this was a known issue that was fixed in 8.2 Update 4. There's also a hot fix that's an updated version of Sitecore.Kernel.dll but they say it should only be used if the kernel's not otherwise patched.

Answer (score 0):

For these publishing issues in 8.2 u3, Sitecore has released a patch which you should integrate. Please refer https://kb.sitecore.net/en/Articles/2017/06/23/10/52/136794.aspx